# $E[\exp(XY)]$=? $X=Z+\epsilon_1$, $Y=Z+\epsilon_2$, $Z, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\sim N(0,1)$, i.i.d.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose $Z, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\sim N(0,1)$, i.i.d. Define $X=Z+\epsilon_1$, $Y=Z+\epsilon_2$. Want to find $E[\exp(XY)]$.

Does anyone have a hint on this? The hard part is how to deal with the exponential function...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\Large E=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty {1\over \sqrt {8\pi^3 }}e^{z^2+(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)z+\epsilon_1\epsilon_2}e^{-{z^2\over 2}}e^{-{\epsilon_1^2\over 2}}e^{-{\epsilon_2^2\over 2}}dz d\epsilon_1d\epsilon_2$$

and use the following $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-{(x-\mu)^2\over 2\sigma^2}}=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Comment: Do you think this integral is convergent? I just tried but the second layer involves a calculation of something like $\int e^{z \epsilon_1} d\epsilon_1$. (I integrated over $\epsilon_2$ first.)

Comment: Honestly saying, I also think that the integral is divergent, which is exactly concluded by the integral. Anyway, this doesn't make the integral wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

(1) You can always do a brute force integration. [Read this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333938/mgf-of-squared-normal-random-variable) if you are still stuck.

(2) The law of total expectation can be useful. Try to calculate conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$ first. You will need to use MGF of normal distribution.